# on AIX, BIRT sees a font, rotatedtext control does not

Tags: birt

We have and AIX/WebSphere server. We have a BIRT engine set up and running. It has worked for four years...since the initial installation. In the last few months, we don't know exactly when, we have seen an issue with the "rotatedtext" control not being able to use a custom font.

If I create a report that shows the custom font in a text field, the font renders exactly as expected. On that same report, a rotatedtext field using that same font reverts to using Sans Serif.

It's maddening because the code didn't change, and our current production system is generating just fine. This appears to only be happening suddenly in our test systems.

What I need to learn is what settings could be causing the font to work in BIRT but not the rotatedtext control.

Is there a recent patch for AIX? It is a Java thing? We have the same fontConfig.xml in the production system, the jars are identical. The custom font is in the same directory on both systems.

Comment: Update: I've discovered that the missing fonts do not appear when I use java to query the graphics environment using the getAllFonts() call. They still appear in the fc-list command.

So now, maybe my question has become "How do I add a font in AIX so that it will always appear in getAllFonts() like our production system does?

Comment: Another update: Our server folks got back to us and told me they need to run smit (System Management Interface Tool), specifically, "smitty font". Not sure, but the "font" part might be a local implementation. The smit tool will run a "mkfont" command in the background. That needs to have root access, and "Adds a font path name to the Object Data Manager (ODM) that is loaded by the low function terminal (LFT) at boot time."

Comment: It is worth noting that BIRT uses the files fontConfig.xml etc. to find fonts, but the RotatedTextItem uses just the usual Java graphics routines (take a look at the source code). This is the reason for the different behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did hunt down the code and found that it was simply using the "font" java constructor. I think it was the getAWTfont paragraph??? I suggested to the developer that this got passed to that she try adding some logic to the paragraph to do a derive / register in order to grab the custom fonts. For now, we have put the fonts into the java_home/jre/lib/fonts directory.

Comment: This raises a weird problem for me. I think the previous developer assumed their changes to the BIRT jar worked. He added the application path to the fontConfig.xml file. I now think the mkfont command was what really fixed the problem three years ago.